# How could a I make BIND 9 generate some log entries?

Tags: logging, bind

I am trying to figure out if I got my BIND server logging to a file correctly so that syslog-ng can read from `named.log`.

Is there anyway to get BIND to generate some log entries to test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could trigger a table reload:

```
pkill -HUP named
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed. Btw syslog-ng is no fun.